# I want insert new value in json which get from sql

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

```
$query2 = "SELECT distinct
                n.id AS 'channel_id',
                n.category_id,
                n.channel_name,
                n.channel_image,
                n.channel_url AS 'channel_url',
                n.channel_description,
                n.channel_type,
                n.video_id,
                c.category_name
            FROM
                tbl_channel n,
                tbl_category c

            WHERE
                n.category_id = c.cid AND c.cid = '$id' 
            ORDER BY n.id DESC 
            LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
    ";
```

I want Insert New Value in Channels url

ex: i got output `channel_url`: `https://edge.okezone.com/live/life.m3u8`
but here i want to insert a new value in end of the url

Comment: What new value do you want to insert? Just use string concatenation: `$row['channel_url'] . $new_value`

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate the output

```
$row['channel_url'] .= "new value";
```

Comment: i want insert $tok="&token=2alsh123" at the end of the url    $row['channel_url'] .= "new value";   this wont work

Comment: you can add $tok to the channel_url element `$row['channel_url'] .= $tok`

Comment: @akashefrathefrath `https://edge.okezone.com/live/life.m3u8&token=2alsh123` would be an invalid URL, `&` should be `?`: `https://edge.okezone.com/live/life.m3u8?token=2alsh123`